# Raspberry OS Pinokio

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bookworm, pi-5

I downloaded Pinokio on my Raspberry Pi 5. I run Fooocus on Pinokio but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raspberry/pinokio/api/fooocus.git/app/entry_with_update.py", line 46, in <module>
    from launch import *
  File "/home/raspberry/pinokio/api/fooocus.git/app/launch.py", line 107, in <module>
    download_models()
  File "/home/raspberry/pinokio/api/fooocus.git/app/launch.py", line 75, in download_models
    load_file_from_url(url=url, model_dir=path_checkpoints, file_name=file_name)
  File "/home/raspberry/pinokio/api/fooocus.git/app/modules/model_loader.py", line 24, in load_file_from_url
    from torch.hub import download_url_to_file
  File "/home/raspberry/pinokio/api/fooocus.git/app/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 237, in <module>
    from torch._C import *  # noqa: F403
ImportError: libopenblasp-r0-85d5f42e.3.25.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```